# Check if any part of element is within copy

Tags: javascript, copy-paste

I have added a copy listener to my element in the red rectangles in this screenshot:

[image]

Highlighting any portion in that rectangle and clicking copy is good, it copies and triggers the event. I can easily tell by testing target.

However if a copy happens after pressing Ctrl+A, then the target is body. Or if i select the label above "GOCR" and then the rectangle below, i get the first text node as target.

I want to be able to tell if the individual rectangles are in the copy, is this possible?

Comment: I can't see the screenshot, can you share a fiddle?

Comment: Why does the user need to 'select', then press 'COPY'. Is it because the user may not want the entire contents?

Comment: @Tigger correct, they may copy only some, but thats not the issue. If they only copy some I still can detect that they copied that node. What I do on copy is increment a count. So user knows which OCR method was most useful to them over history. The problem is when they make one big selection which contains one or multiple, in this case i need to detect which elements are contained.

Comment: @gurvinder372 I'll try to write up some code with this specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Been thinking about this and came up with using CSS to prevent select on everything except the selectable areas. Like so:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body style="-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;user-select:none;">
This is some text in the body.
<div>ORC: <button id="copy">Copy</button></div>
<div style="border:1px solid red;-webkit-user-select:text;-moz-user-select:text;user-select:text">
Selectable only text area.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Would this work in your case?

Comment: Thanks so much I also came up with a solution, it relied on `SelectionRange` object. I couldn't get the `SelectionRange` object from the `copy` event, so I just made an assumption then when a copy event triggers, it is on the `window.getSelection()`. I then did `if (window.getSelection().containsNode(mynode, true)` to determine if my node was within the copy and its working great. Although I wish I could get the `SelectionRange` object from `copy` event. My code is in ReactJS so I didn't port it out to show here yet, but will do asap :)

Comment: This is my code in reactjs - https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot/blob/master/app/js/app_ocr.js#L67-L89

Comment: The CSS to not select anything is cool, however if they select a part of the selectable area, and then click somewhere to deslect, it wont deselect unless they click in a selectable area. Then it still persists which single or multiple nodes were selected. As I have up to 3 different nodes. I'll show you the implementation, I implemented it in my firefox addon, do you use firefox?